# What visualization was used for ICA in the tissue experiment?

Tags: gene, unsupervised-learning

I want to run the experiments in mentioned in [enter the matrix](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168952518301240#bib0205).

For the the plot in figure 3B it mentioned that

> The relative absolute value of the magnitude of each element in the
> pattern matrix indicates the extent to which that sample contributes
> to the corresponding source of variation. The sign of the values
> indicate over- or underexpression in that factor depending on the sign
> of the corresponding gene weights in the amplitude matrix. As a
> result, the values can be plotted on the y axis against known
> covariates on the x axis to directly interpret the relationship
> between samples. When applied to GTEx, we observe one pattern
> associated with cerebellum, another pattern that has large positive
> values for one donor and large negative values for another donor, and
> eight other patterns associated with other sources of variation
> (supplemental information online).

I calculated the ICA with `head()`

```
        PC1       PC2
0  1.317276 -0.682285
1  1.696110 -0.549004
2  0.037709 -0.548736
3  0.702004 -0.545255
4  1.227363 -0.574219
```

but fail to see how the authors plotted their ICA graphs